# Using Bitcoin with MEAN stack

Tags: database, website-integration, user-data

I want to make a web app that accepts and uses Bitcoin, complete with user accounts, bitcoin storage per user, etc.  How would I go about hooking this up using MEAN?  Is there a reference for setting up a bitcoin user account database RDBMS model or a SQL/noSQL reference that you can suggest?

Comment: I don't think it would be particularly different from LAMP. You'd use different libraries, sure, but you've got the same problems to solve: creating addresses, detecting payments, secure key storage, etc.